# How this Javascript can be integrated properly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calculator

Good Day all,

Please I'm still pretty much learning the ropes. I'm trying to make an auto calculator script to calculate price (discount given based on quantity) and display the results in a text field.

I wrote a javascript but it doesn't seem to work in this sample html page I'm testing it on.

```
<html>
        <p>price calculator ( Rate: N1.50 )</p>
        <br />
        <label for="units">Units:</label>
        <input name="units" type="text" id="units" value="1000" />
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var parray = "1000-9999:1.9; 10000-49999:1.8; 50000-99999:1.5; 100000-9999999:1.4; 10000000-0:1.4;";
            var prices = parray.split(';');

            var mins   = new Array();
            var maxs   = new Array();
            var rates  = new Array();

            for (var index in prices)
            {
                var price = prices[index];
                var m = price.split(':');
                if(m.length != 2) continue;
                var u = m[0].split('-');

                if(u.length == 2 && mins.length == maxs.length && maxs.length == rates.length)
                {
                    rates[rates.length] = parseFloat(m[1]);
                    mins[mins.length]   = parseFloat(u[0]);
                    maxs[maxs.length]   = parseFloat(u[1]);
                }
            }

            var pricemins = new Array();
            var pricemaxs = new Array();

            for(var i = 0; i < mins.length; i++)
            {
                pricemins[i] = rates[i]* mins[i];
                pricemaxs[i] = rates[i]* maxs[i];
            }


        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#units').keyup(function(){

                    var units = parseInt($('#units').attr('value'));
                    var rate  = 0;
                    for(var i = 0; i < mins.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(units >= mins[i] && (units <= maxs[i] || maxs[i] == 0)) {
                            rate = rates[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    var amount = units * rate;
                    if(amount == NaN) amount = 0;
                    if(rate == 0)
                    {
                        $('#amount').attr('value', '--');
                        $('#price_rate').html('price calculator ( Rate: ? -- )');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#amount').attr('value', amount.toFixed(2));
                        $('#price_rate').html('price calculator ( Rate: ?' + rate.toFixed(2) + ' )');
                    }
            });

            $('#units').keyup();

            /////////////////////////////

            $('#amount').keyup(function(){

                    var amount = parseInt($('#amount').attr('value'));
                    var rate   = 0;

                    for(var i = 0; i < pricemins.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(amount >= pricemins[i] && (amount <= pricemaxs[i] || pricemaxs[i] == 0)) {
                            rate = rates[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    var units = parseInt(amount/rate);
                    if(units == NaN) units = 0;

                    if(rate == 0)
                    {
                        $('#units').attr('value', '--');
                        $('#price_rate').html('price calculator ( Rate: ? -- )');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#units').attr('value', units);
                        $('#price_rate').html('price calculator ( Rate: ?' + rate.toFixed(2) + ' )');
                    }
            });

            $('#amount').keyup();
          });
        </script>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label for="amount">Price: </label>
        <input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" style="width:100px" />
</html>
```

Comment: You haven’t described what precisely the problems are, but one thing that jumps out is `== NaN`. You can’t compare to `NaN` with `==`, because `NaN !== NaN`. Use `amount !== amount` or `isNaN(amount)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) to test your work. I've separated the markup from the JS, and replaced your `.keyUp()` approach with `.on()` event delegation. There appears to be a few issues with your code though, as it's still not all the way there. Hope this helps you on the right path: http://jsfiddle.net/3dRhn/

```
$('#units').on('keyup', function () {
    //etc
});

$('#amount').on('keyup', function () {
    //etc
});
```

Comment: Your script needs to interact with the document after it's fully loaded. This is one (of many) reasons that it should be separated from the markup.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to reply. Yes. I just seem to be stuck at this point, on my main html file where this code is used it only calculates the initial value while the page is loading, once fully loaded, it stops working. On the jsfiddle page it appears to do the same however.

Comment: You might attempt to trace the values through the script with `console.log()`s, to make sure that they're passing through and available where expected.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've seen the problem, on the jsfiddle page, when I checked the "Migrate 1.2.1" box and run it everything works fine. I added "<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>" to my main html page (head) and it does seem to work okay. Hopefully this won't conflict with the other jquery 1.9 script that's loaded as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review page structure in Html. You need more than an  tag surrounding the document.  You also appear to be using methods defined in the javascript framework jQuery.

At a minimum, I think you need the following (from: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/, with modifications so you don't have to download the jQuery library to test it out.).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- put your html here -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    // Your code goes here.

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

to break this down:
before you use jQuery, you will need to include the library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery is a Javascript framework, that is a set of methods and or objects that simplify and or standardize the use of Javascript across different browser implementations of javascript.  This loads those methods, so that you can use them.

once you have loaded jQuery, you can use javascript as you are in your example above.  You will need to correct some errors, that other posters have mentioned.

```
<script>

    // Your code goes here.

</script>
```

For more in-depth info on html5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/

For more info on jQuery http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Hello, Thanks for taking the time to respond. Actually, I've structured it properly in my main project html file, the problem is, it only calculates the "initial" value on pageload, but after the page completes loading the calculator

Comment: Apologies, this was meant for the earlier answer given by Stuart.

Comment: Ah, understood.  In that case, I think @Stuart will get you on your way.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for taking the time to respond and the resources you gave. It will help me learn more! I'm much grateful.